# Integral related to the softplus function

Tags: integration, logarithms, improper-integrals, polylogarithm

Let
$$
f(x) = \log(1+e^{2x+1}) - 2\log(1 + e^{2x}) + \log(1 + e^{2x-1}).
$$
According to Wolfram Alpha,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \frac 12.\tag{$*$}
$$
$f(x)$ is a "bump function" built out of the [softplus function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#Softplus) $y=\log(1 + e^x)$, that I want to use as a kernel for nonparametric regression. I want to normalize $f(x)$ to have integral $1$, and the definite integral (*) gives the normalizing factor.

But I can't figure out how to do the integral by hand.
Substitution gives (and Wolfram Alpha confirms)
$$
\int f(x)\,dx
= \operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{2x}) - \frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{2x-1})
- \frac12\operatorname{Li}_2(-e^{2x+1}) + C,
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$ is the [dilogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function). I haven't had any success in applying dilogarithm identities to the above, though.

Can anyone give a derivation of $(*)$?

Comment: Your real problem is to understand how to obtain this $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = \frac 12$? Btw from where is this problem?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The context of the question is that f(x) is a "bump function" built out of the softmax function y=log(1 + e^x), that I want to use as a kernel for nonparametric regression. I want to normalize f(x) to have integral 1, and the definite integral (*) gives the normalizing factor.

Comment: You may ignore this, as it's kinda off topic. But what is the use of all this in artificial intelligence? It looks interesting to me and I want to learn some AI too, mind sharing some tips?

Comment: The functions nf(x/n), n=1,2,... is a sequence of bump function centered at x=0. Such functions are typically used as kernels for nonparametric kernel regression. Since f(x) is a linear combination of translates of the softplus function, these regression functions are the outputs of a neural network with a single hidden layer with softplus activation. Softplus is a smooth approximation rectified linear function r(x)=max(x, 0), which is the kind of activation function you'll typically see in hidden layers of neural networks. Because it's smooth, softplus is often more convenient to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equal to $I(1/2)$ where, for real $a>0$, \begin{align}I(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\log\frac{\cosh(x+a)\cosh(x-a)}{\cosh^2 x}\,dx\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{a}\left(\tanh(x+y)-\tanh(x-y)\right)\,dy\,dx\\&=\int_{0}^{a}\left.\log\frac{\cosh(x+y)}{\cosh(x-y)}\right|_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty}\,dy=4\int_{0}^{a}y\,dy=2a^2.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{(1+e^{2x}\cdot e)(1+e^{2x}/e)}{(1+e^{2x})^2}\right)dx\overset{e^{2x}\to x}=\frac12 \int_0^\infty\ln\left(\frac{(1+ex)(1+x/e)}{(1+x)^2}\right)\frac{dx}{x} $$
$$\overset{IBP}=\frac12\int_0^\infty \ln x \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{e+x}\right)dx+\frac12\int_0^\infty \ln x \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{e}{1+ex}\right)dx$$

$$\int_0^\infty \ln x \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{e}{1+ex}\right)dx\overset{x\to \frac{1}{x}}=\int_0^\infty \ln x \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{e+x}\right)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\int_0^\infty \ln x \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{e+x}\right)dx\overset{x\to \frac{e}{x}}=\int_0^\infty \ln \left(\frac{e}{x}\right) \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{e+x}\right)dx$$

Summing up the two integrals from above gives:
$$2I=\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{1}{e+x}\right)dx\Rightarrow I=\frac12 \ln\left(\frac{1+x}{e+x}\right)\bigg|_0^\infty=\frac12$$